# In PHP, how do I let other methods in my class know when an exception was thrown from within another method?

Tags: php, oop

I have a method that translates HTML into another language. Inside that method is a try, catch block that handles network errors. I have another method that returns true if an error occurred. And another that displays the error message.

However, I have not found a way to let either method know when the translation fails.

Here's the method that handles the actual translation (It is part of a trait called Translate). $status is an array that is a variable in the class TranslateContent that uses this trait.

```php
  protected function translateHTML(object $translator, string $content, string $target_language, array $status):string {
    
    if($target_language == 'en'){
      
      return $content;
    
    } 
        
    if($content):
        
        try{

          $content_translated = $translator->translateText($content, 'en', $target_language, 
              ['tag_handling' => 'html'], 
              ['formality', 'prefer_less'],
              ['split_sentences', 0]
            );

          return $content_translated;

        } catch(Exception $error){

          $status['status'] = true;
          $status['message'] = $error->getMessage();

          return $content;
        }

    endif;

    return $content;

  }
```

At the top of the class called TranslateContent that uses trait Translate, I declare $status:

```php
 protected $status = [
      'error' => false,
      'message' => ''
    ];
```

Then here is the method that uses the translateHTML() method where the exception is thrown. The last argument I've added is the status array created above. (Note: I am passing an incorrect target language here to trigger the exception.)

```php
public function translatePostContent(string $content):string {

        $post_language = $this->getPostLanguage($this->post_id);
        
        $target_language = $post_language['deepl_language_code'];

        return $this->translateHTML($this->translator, $content, 'doesnt-exist', $this->status );

    }
```

And lastly that methods that return the status:

```php
public function hasError():bool{

      return $this->status['error'];

      
    }

public function getErrorMessage():string{
      
      return $this->status['message'];

    }
```

My thinking was, if an exception is thrown during the translation attempt, I need to update the state of $status from the within the catch block. But the $status is not being updated. Instead the code where TranslateContent is instantiated runs as if there was no error at all.

I thought this was a scoping issue initially but from what I've read, catch blocks do not have scoping in PHP.

What am I missing?

Comment: You're not doing anything with `$status`, you're just setting a value and then throwing it away. You have a few options -- you'll need to either return the status, throw an exception with the status embedded it it,  save state in the object and provide something like a `getLastError()` method to read that state, or (if you want the value of `$status` to be actually changed by the function) then you'll need to [pass by reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php).

Comment: Catching the exception inside `translateHTML()` and returning untranslated data doesn't make sense at all. Let the exception bubble up to the calling function and let _that_ decide what it wants to do, whether it's using the untranslated data or something else. If you want to log an error in the `translateHTML()` call you can catch and then _re-throw_ the exception for handling higher up. Similarly, catching an exception, and then setting a catch-all `$something_happened = true` variable that you have to manually check for is kind of the antithesis of using exceptions in the first place.

Comment: @AlexHowansky I can't believe I didn't catch that. Thanks! I have this personal rule where I don't let traits directly update the state of the class using them, and that's what got me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like what you want is to pass "by reference" the `$status` variable.

You can do so by redefining your `translateHTML` signature prefixing with `&` your `$status` variable:

```
  protected function translateHTML(object $translator, string $content, string $target_language, array &$status):string {
```

That way when you "edit" the variable you will be editing the actual variable passed to the method (and not a copy, which is the default).

The above should work, but maybe you might want to move the $status property to the trait itself. That way you can access it by using `$this->status` and you won't need to pass it at all.

Comment: I knew it was going to be something simple. I have this personal rule where I try to not let traits directly update state and that's what got me.

Answer (score 1):

You declare `$status` like this:

```
protected $status = [
      'error' => false,
      'message' => ''
    ];
```

but your `catch` block makes two mistakes:

```
    $status['status'] = true;
    $status['message'] = $error->getMessage();
```

You should be updating `$this->status`, and you should be setting `$this->status['error']`, like this:

```
    $this->status['error'] = true;
    $this->status['message'] = $error->getMessage();
```

Then your call to `translateHTML()` has no need to pass in the `$status` variable.

```
return $this->translateHTML($this->translator, $content, 'doesnt-exist');
```

Your methods to retrieve the error status and message are correctly accessing the class property, so they should now work.

There's no need to pass `$status` by reference, or at all. That's what class properties are for.